# Compilation fails in libvpx while building CSipSimple source

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, csip-simple

I am trying to build CSipSimple for android by following the steps mentioned here https://sourceforge.net/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild/?version=1 but facing following issue after executing make command :-

make
make[1]: Entering directory /home/tajintder/Desktop/Drive_D/CSipSimple-master/jni/libvpx' Cloning into 'sources'... fatal: repository 'https://code.google.com/p/webm.libvpx/' not found /bin/sh: 2: cd: can't cd to sources fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/tajintder/Desktop/Drive_D) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set). fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/tajintder/Desktop/Drive_D) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set). fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/tajintder/Desktop/Drive_D) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set). make[1]: *** [sources] Error 128 make[1]: Leaving directory/home/tajintder/Desktop/Drive_D/CSipSimple-master/jni/libvpx'
make: *** [jni/libvpx/sources] Error 2

It would be nice if anyone can help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error
I solved it by downloading the repository manually from [here](http://www.webmproject.org/code/)
Extract the files in /jni/libvpx/
It should have one folder named libvpx
Change the directory name to sources
Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for the response . I will try your solution